# Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in /<directoryA>/<directoryB>/public_html/PHP/functions/Users.php on line 18

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have been running some PHP code on my local machine(Running PHP Version 5.3.8) for some time using the $stmt functions for querying, all the code seemed to work perfectly. I have now bought some hosting with HostGator(Running PHP Version 5.2.17) and the $stmt functions do not seem to be recognised, to be exact I get the following error :

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in    /<directoryA>/<directoryB>/public_html/PHP/functions/Users.php on line 18
```

And here is the code it is referring to :

```
$username = $this->_generalFunctions->sanatize($username, $this->_databaseInfo);
$query = $this->_databaseInfo->_link->prepare("SELECT id FROM userlogin WHERE username = ?");
$query->bind_param('s', $username);
$query->execute();
$array = $query->get_result()->fetch_array();
   /*Line 18*/ if(!$array== 1){
    return false;
}else{
    return true;
}
```

I'm fairly sure this function should be in the PHP version so I can't identify the problem, thanks for any helpful answers to the problem or any hints at all in advance.

Comment: if you were add the very error message in the question title (making it fit for the programming question rather than novel), you'd be suggested with dozen already answered questions.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, your guess is wrong.
"This function" is not necessarily available as it exists only if mysqldnd driver is used.

Comment: In that case, what would you suggest would be a work around, the only function actually causing an error there is "get_result()"

Comment: I reckon there are plenty of bind_result() based solutions in the comments on get_result manual page